# Separating background process and application in a list obtained using tasklist

Tags: c++, windows

How do I separate the system.exe's from the current apps running obtained from tasklist or any other such sources

```
  Caption               CommandLine                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
System Idle Process                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
System                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
smss.exe              \SystemRoot\System32\smss.exe                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 

wininit.exe           wininit.exe                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   

services.exe          C:\windows\system32\services.exe                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
winlogon.exe          winlogon.exe                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
lsass.exe             C:\windows\system32\lsass.exe                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
lsm.exe               C:\windows\system32\lsm.exe                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
svchost.exe           C:\windows\system32\svchost.exe -k DcomLaunch    

OUTLOOK.EXE           "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft  Office\Office15\OUTLOOK.EXE"
```

The above was generated using wmic.. I wanted to separate outlook from the rest of the processes.

Comment: What is system.exe's?

Comment: Background processes

Comment: Do you mean services?

Comment: @Drop Yes.. I mean the list displays all exe that are currently running in the system. I want to filter out the windows related process. Only the applications like Outlook, VStudio etc etc.

Comment: There is no such thing as "system" or "windows-related" or even "background" exe's exist. You need to be conscious about what you want exactly. Read some documentation to get an idea. There is a completely idiotic solution to filter out processes by path. `C:\windows\system32\*` is certainly something  "system" or "windows-related".

Comment: @Drop Im trying to figure ot a way to obtain the information present in the Application tab in the task manager of Windows. I have the information about all the processes so was trying to obtain that from the list as I mentioned in the question